# nginx routing do diffrent path with angular are not working

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

Hey together I have an issue with my angular project routing in my Kubernetes Cluster. I explain how I proceed I want my start root in the url is not / but /login everything should start with /login, this does the Angular application, but as soon as I load it with docker in a nginx and put it in the Kubernetes cluster and in tearafik ingress change the url routing to /login instead of / the following error occurs in the web console:

```
efused to apply style from 'https://XXXXXXt/styles.css' because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
login:14 GET XXXXXXXXXXX/runtime.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
login:14 GET XXXXXXXXXXX/polyfills.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
login:14 GET XXXXXXXXXXX/scripts.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
login:14 GET XXXXXXXXXXXet/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
```

I explain how I proceed
In Angular I am routing everything so:

```
  {
    path: '', component: DefaultComponent,
  },

  {
    path: 'conformity-report',
    loadChildren: () => import('./all-products/conformity-report/conformity-report.module').then(m => m.ConformityReportModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'user-management', canActivate: [AdminGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./all-products/user-management/user-management.module').then(m => m.UserManagementModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'configuration-area', canActivate: [AdminGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./all-products/configuration-area/configuration-area.module').then(m => m.ConfigurationAreaModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'admin', canActivate: [AdminGuard],
    loadChildren: () => import('./all-products/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'error-page',
    component: ErrorPageComponent
  },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
  
];
```

This is my nginx configuration file

```
  server {
    listen 8080;
    server_name  localhost;
 
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
 
    gzip on;
    gzip_min_length 1000;
    gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
 
    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
      include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }
    location ~ \.css {
    add_header  Content-Type    text/css;
    }
    location ~ \.js {
    add_header  Content-Type    application/x-javascript;
    }    
  }
```

This is my dockerfile where I move the compialed application to nginx with the configuration file

```
FROM  XXXXXXX/nodejs:14.17 as build

ENV XXXXXXXX


WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json /app/
 
COPY . .
RUN npm install 

RUN npm run build 

FROM    XXXXXXX/nginx:unpriviliged
EXPOSE 8080:8080

COPY  --from=build  /app/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

COPY  --from=build /app/dist/projectname /usr/share/nginx/html
```

My Deployment and Service File are working properly but i will past my Ingress file here We are using taerafik

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
    #traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer:XXXXXX-acme

  name: ingresshosts
  namespace: dev
spec:
  rules:
    - host: XXXXXXXX
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend
                port:
                  number: 8080
                              
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - XXXXXXXX
      secretName: XXXXXXXX
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: on top of the annotation solution proposed below make the following changes: remove the include in the **/** location (it's already present in the parent context), the other two locations arent needed (when the files are retrieved from the files in the browser (like the js and CSS files) the routing isn't needed since it routes to the file path and isn't used anyway)

Comment: I added now / login and it is still not working

Comment: I added now / login and it is still not working  '''apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
    #traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /login
    raefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/app-root: "/login"
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: xxxxx-acme
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rule-type: "PathPrefixStrip"
  rules:

      http:
        paths:
          - path: /login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Everyone the solution is at in the angular application `angular.json` a **basheref**

```
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "baseHref": "/login/", 
........
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the annoation in ingress

```
traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /login
```

**Example**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: traefik
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /login
    traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.tls: "true"
    #traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/router.entrypoints: websecure
    cert-manager.io/cluster-issuer: daimler-acme

  name: ingresshosts
  namespace: dev
spec:
  rules:
    - host: XXXXXXXX
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: frontend
                port:
                  number: 8080
                              
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - XXXXXXXX
      secretName: XXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Unfortanatly nothing is changed

Comment: `traefik.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation was removed in traefik v2